# How to Display extra files in QtCreator project tree (CMake-project)?

Tags: android, qt, cmake

In qmake-project i can use `OTHER_FILES += "android/AndroidManifest.xml"` to display AndroidManifest.xml at QtCreator's project tree,
how to do similar with CMake project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [add_custom_target](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_target.html) in cmake. Example:

```
add_custom_target(android-related-files SOURCES "android/AndroidManifest.xml")
```

will show something like this:

[image: add_custom_target result example]